# Explain this chained inequality

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Under what scenario would the following chained inequality be true?

```
33353 > 48484 > 37465 > 96166 > 71373 > 87285 > 26938
```

Notes:

- `>` means "greater than"
- The transitive property is in effect

Answer (score 25, accepted):

These are obviously

> Poker hands, sorted by which hands are better!

Explanation:

> 33353 is 4 of a kind
>  48484 is a full house
>  37465 is a straight (we'll assume it's not a straight flush)
>  96166 is 3 of a kind
>  71373 is 2 pair
>  87285 is a pair
>  26938 is 9-high (we'll also assume it's not a flush)

Answer (score 8):

> [Modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) $726$: $683>568>439>334>225>165>76$
>  or
>  Modulo $727$: $638>502>388>202>127>45>39$

Comment: Usually inequalities are not very applicable in modular arithmetic since it depends on your residue system. But nice answer anyway!

Comment: To expand on @Riley 's comment, while computer programs generally return x mod y as an integer, mathematically it's generally treated as being a member of a distinct mathematical structure.  x mod y is the *equivalence class* of all numbers that, when divided by y, have the same remainder as x does.

Comment: @Acccumulation Algebraically, it's a coset, but I don't think puzzle answers need always delve into mathematical precision :)

Comment: @noedne : It's both.  It's an equivalence under the equivalence relation "$ a \sim b \iff a \cong b \pmod{n}$".  It's a coset in the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.